# how to make an UI like an alert dialog and its button(like ok and cancel)works as tabs

Tags: android, ios

i want make an UI similar to alert dialog which comes on click event and button of that UI(eg. OK,Cancel) should work like tabs. as if i click on tab1 it should load contents of tab1 and so on. actually it should look like an tab activity which comparatively smaller than main activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html).
Hope its help

EDIT
[Simple example of using PopupWindow with custom layout](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)

EDIT2 especially for MoJo

popup_layout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/popup_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a android:id="@+id/tv_1"
            />

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a android:id="@+id/tv_2"
            />
         <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>^
```

Activity onClick Event

```
private void initializedPopup()
{
try {
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ConfirmActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_main));
    // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
    pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
    // display the popup in the center
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    mText1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
    mText1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_2);
    Button btn1 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener );

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    pw.dismiss();
}
};
```

Comment: Try to add some code dude as *Link answers* aren't considered as a complete answer

Comment: I didn't ask you to put more links but to put directly what's on the link. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dialog Dr=new dialog(this);
Dr.setcontentview(R.layout.main);
Dr.show();
```

Comment: Use. All widgets having dialog reference. Like Button b=(Button)Dr.findviewbyid(R.I'd.button1);

Comment: can we use tabs in dialog? i want to change the content on tabchanged listener.

Comment: Now using above create any layout having tab or anything and display as dialog

Answer (score 0):

Do as you do for a normal activity. Then add this in your **styles.xml**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Then set this as theme for your activity

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityName"
            android:label="@string/DialogTheme" >
```